# Eureka peers not synchronized

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix, netflix-eureka

I'm prototyping a set of Spring Cloud + Netflix OSS applications and have run into trouble with Eureka. In our setup, we have a Spring Cloud Config Server + Eureka Server, and then 2 modules that utilize that server component for bootstrapping and service discovery.

The problem I run into is that if I spin up 2 instances of the Eureka Server and try to pair them (based on the **Two Peer Aware Eureka Servers** in [the docs](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html)) they don't synchronize with each other. See configs below and/or [the code on GitHub](https://github.com/dwelch2344/distributed-spring).

Essentially, Peer1 starts up and looks fine. Peer2 will startup and look fine, with both peers showing each other in the services. However, if the "UserService" module spins up and registers itself with Peer1, Peer2 will never see it. If we then spin up the "Web" module pointing to Peer2, it can never resolve the UserService. They basically act in isolation.

I've tried several combinations of setting the `serviceUrl` both on the server and the instance of the Eureka servers but to no avail. Am I just configuring things wrong?

**Peer 1 / default config:**

```
server:
  port: 8888

eureka:
  dashboard:
    path: /dashboard
  instance:
    hostname: peer1
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 3
  client:
      serviceUrl:
          defaultZone: ${eureka.server.serviceUrl:http://localhost:${server.port}/eureka/}
  server:
    serviceUrl:
        defaultZone: http://localhost:${server.port}/eureka/
        peer2: http://peer2/eureka/
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0


spring:
  application:
    name: demo-config-service
  profiles:
    active: native
  # required for Spring Cloud Bus
  rabbitmq:
    host: ${DOCKER_IP:192.168.59.103}
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password: guest
    virtualHost: /
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        prefix: /configs
        native:
          searchLocations: /Users/dave/workspace/oss/distributed-spring/modules/config-server/src/main/resources/testConfigs
#        git :
#          uri: https://github.com/joshlong/microservices-lab-configuration
```

**Peer 2 config:**

```
server:
  port: 8889

eureka:
  dashboard:
    path: /dashboard
  instance:
    hostname: peer2
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 3
  client:
      serviceUrl:
          defaultZone: ${eureka.server.serviceUrl:http://localhost:${server.port}/eureka/}
  server:
    serviceUrl:
        defaultZone: http://localhost:8888/eureka/
        peer1: http://peer1/eureka/
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0


spring:
  application:
    name: demo-config-service
  profiles:
    active: native
  # required for Spring Cloud Bus
  rabbitmq:
    host: ${DOCKER_IP:192.168.59.103}
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password: guest
    virtualHost: /
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        prefix: /configs
        native:
          searchLocations: /Users/dave/workspace/oss/distributed-spring/modules/config-server/src/main/resources/testConfigs
#        git :
#          uri: https://github.com/joshlong/microservices-lab-configuration
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There were a few problems.  The `defaultZone` needs to be in the client section as noted in the docs.  The `defaultZone` url needs the port.

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       peer1
127.0.0.1       peer2
```

**Peer 1 Config (Partial)**

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: peer1
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 3
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://peer2:8889/eureka/
```

**Peer 2 Config (Partial)**

```
eureka:
  dashboard:
    path: /dashboard
  instance:
    hostname: peer2
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 3
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://peer1:8888/eureka/
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
```

**User service config (Partial)** Config port was wrong.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: user-service
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888/configs
```

You can see user-service replicated to both peer1 and peer2.  I can post a PR to your code if you want.

**Peer 1**

[image: Peer1]

**Peer 2**

[image: Peer2]

Comment: Awesome! I'll try it in a few. I realize where I went wrong: I thought that naming my eureka services peer1/2 would allow them to lookup each other via the registry. But that's where the long lived (elastic IPs in my case) are useful.

Comment: I have a question on this.  For the user service configuration, are you setting the eureka configuration to defaultZone: http://peer1:8888/eureka/,http://peer2:8888/eureka/ in order to have failover in case peer1 fails?

Comment: Yeah Larry, that's the idea

Comment: the peer1 & peer2 config, should both the configurations be in same application.yml inside my Eureka.jar ? and will i have to run 2 instances of Eureka , each one with profile name peer1 & peer2 ?

Answer (score 3):

@spencergibb's didn't mention why this hack-ish workaround is required.  There is a gotcha with running more than one Eureka server on the same host. Netflix code (`com.netflix.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes.isThisMyUrl`) filters out the peer URLs that are on the same host. This may have been done to prevent the server registering as its own peer (I’m guessing here) but because they don’t check for the port, peer awareness doesn’t work unless the Eureka hostnames in the `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone` are different. The hacky workaround for this is to define unique hostnames and then map them to `127.0.0.1` in the `/etc/hosts` file (or its Windows equivalent).

I've created a blog post with the details of Eureka [here](http://blog.asarkar.com/technical/netflix-eureka), that fills in some missing detail from Spring doc or Netflix blog. It is the result of several days of debugging and digging through source code.