# Can I Enrol One Micro services at 2 Different eureka

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I don't know whether it is possible or not. I want to know whether I can enroll one microservice at two different eureka server at once.

I have one MS let say API-GATEWAY:
I want to enrol it on two different eureka registry server running on 8761 and 8762.

for that I write:

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl: 
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/ , http://localhost:8762/eureka/
    registry-fetch-interval-seconds: 1000
  instance:
    hostname: api-gateway
    prefer-ip-address: true
    lease-renewal-interval-in-seconds: 5000000
    lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 5000000
```

First up all tell me is it possible or not?
If yes, what property should I use to achieve the objectives?

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one defaultZone. You need peer replication. So that your 8761/eureka is synchronized with 8762/eureka. When the application is registered to 8761  it is also available in 8762. To do this see [@spencergibb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2730527/spencergibb) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288959/eureka-peers-not-synchronized).