# Unable to register multiple instance of eureka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker-compose, netflix-eureka

I am trying to create two instance of Eureka server.But when i run it they are unable to register each other. Error i am getting is:

> com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
>   2017-11-02 15:51:14.125 ERROR 34 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error
>
> com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
>       at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar!/:1.19.1]

Main application file is:

```js
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class RegistrationServer {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "registration-server");

  SpringApplication.run(RegistrationServer.class, args);
 }
}
```

registration-server.yml is:

```js
---
spring.profiles: server-1
    
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost #eureka-server
  server:
    enableSelfPreservation: false
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    serviceUrl:
     defaultZone: http://server-2:2424/eureka/
     

server:
  port: 2323   # HTTP (Tomcat) port
  
  
  
spring:
 application:
  name: eureka-server1
---

spring.profiles: server-2
    
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost #eureka-server
  server:
    enableSelfPreservation: false
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    serviceUrl:
     defaultZone: http://server-1:2323/eureka/
     

server:
  port: 2424   # HTTP (Tomcat) port
  
  
  
spring:
 application:
  name: eureka-server2
---
```

docker-compose file is:

```js
version: '2'
services:
  lb:
   image: dockercloud/haproxy
   volumes:
     - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
   ports:
     - "80:80"
     - "1936:1936"

  eureka-service-1:
    image: qaregistry.test.com/registration-server:0.0.2
    ports:
     - "2323:2323"
    environment:
     - APPBINARY=registration-server.jar
     - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=server-1"
    extra_hosts:
     - "server-1:127.0.0.1"
     - "server-2:127.0.0.1"
    entrypoint:
     - /usr/bin/jarrun.sh
     - QA

  eureka-service-2:
    image: qaregistry.test.com/registration-server:0.0.2
    ports:
     - "2424:2424"
    environment:
     - APPBINARY=registration-server.jar
     - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=server-2"
    extra_hosts:
     - "server-1:127.0.0.1"
     - "server-2:127.0.0.1"
    entrypoint:
     - /usr/bin/jarrun.sh
     - QA
```

pox.xml is:

```js
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
   <artifactId>registration-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>

  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <!-- Setup Spring Boot -->
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <!-- Setup Spring MVC & REST, use Embedded Tomcat -->
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  
  <dependency>
   <!-- Spring Cloud starter -->
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <!-- Eureka service registration -->
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
 </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Brixton.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>  
     <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

                     <!-- added by linux team for docker integration with maven -->
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>0.4.13</version>
                                <configuration>
                                        <serverId>dockerhub</serverId>
                                        <imageName>qaregistry.test.com/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</imageName>
                                         <pullOnBuild>true</pullOnBuild>
                                         <registryUrl>https://qaregistry.test.com</registryUrl>
                                        <baseImage>qaregistry.test.com/test-jdk:8u121</baseImage>
                                        <maintainer>USER user@test.com</maintainer>
                                        <labels>
                                                <label>ProductName=${project.build.finalName}</label>
                                        </labels>
                                        <user>test</user>
                                        <entryPoint>["/usr/bin/jarrun.sh"]</entryPoint>
                                        <resources>
                                           <resource>
                                                  <targetPath>/data/test/run/</targetPath>
                                                  <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                                                  <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                                          </resource>
                                        </resources>        
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
  
 
 
</project>
```

**Both instance of eureka i.e. server-1 and server-2 are running fine. but they are not registering each other.**

> Screenshots are attached for more info: [server-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nw9sd.png)
>   [server-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw7OT.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to revise your registration-server.yml as follows, you missed **ONE** space before `defaultZone` for both .yml files. BTW, there are still many syntax errors in those files.

For eureka-server-1:

```
eureka:
  ...
  client:
    ...
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://server-2:2424/eureka/
```

For eureka-server-2:

```
eureka:
  ...
  client:
    ...
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://server-1:2323/eureka/
```

Here comes one of my eureka server settings, it works pretty fine for both servers to register to each other:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: registry

server:
  port: 2323

eureka:
  server:
    eviction-interval-timer-in-ms: 15000
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${eureka_url:http://localhost:2424/eureka}
  instance:  
    instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${random.value} 
    hostname: ${eureka_host:localhost} 
    secure-port: ${server.port}
    non-secure-port-enabled: true
    non-secure-port: ${server.port}
```

Comment: hi @LHCHIN , I just tried your eureka server settings, still facing the same issue.

Comment: One question: Why do you add `System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "registration-server");` in your main function? Please remove it and try again. Good luck!

Comment: so that spring can pick configured properties from there.

Comment: But my eureka servers can be executed normally after I adding this code.

Comment: I have set same "spring.application.name" for both servers profiles..... and now my code is working fine . But I don't know how it worked!!

Answer (score 1):

Look at this post [Eureka peers not synchronized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288959/eureka-peers-not-synchronized)

and this project https://github.com/dwelch2344/distributed-spring

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether Eureka can register an another Eureka, but conceptually looks like its also a service which is running. And thus can act as both service and server(eureka). But I am not fully sure.

Anyways, I think you should try this in your Eurekaserverapplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableEurekaServer
public class RegistrationServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.config.name", "registration-server");

        SpringApplication.run(RegistrationServer.class, args);
    }
}
```

Just try to put `@EnableEurekaClient` or `@EnableDiscoveryClient` for the boot application. Since your application is supposed to act as both client and server.
SO, I think those annotations are important.

Comment: Hi Sakura, I have tried your solution but it is not working..Still getting the same issue.

Comment: are you able to access both eureka server through a browser?

Comment: Yes, i am able to access both eureka server through a browser.

Comment: @JitendraSingh Is your yml file correct? spacing doesn't look correct on the `defaultZone` key line? can you just check line by line again. Then do a clean build and run.

Comment: Hi @sakura, I have checked the spacing, it is correct. Although I added an extra space before **defaultZone** and now both servers are unable to find *DS Replicas*. (Previous they were able to find DS Replicas)

Comment: Hi @sakura, I have added screenshot...hope you will get more info.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure , try to change

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname
```

to the 'server-1' and 'server-2' accordingly

Comment: Hi borino, tried your solution. it is not helpful, Still getting the same issue.