# Microservices not registering on all Eureka Instances

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, high-availability

Spring Boot version: 2.1.6.RELEASE

Spring Cloud Version: Greenwich.SR1

Objective is to set up two instances of Eureka Servers in a cluster and have all microservices registered to both, in order to achieve HA. Currently I am testing this on my local machine running Ubuntu 18.04.

So as mentioned in the official docs, I have set up the peer to peer awareness of Eureka Instances. On bringing both the Eureka Server Instances up, on the dashboard of Instance-1(Port 8080) under available replicas showing Instance-2 name and on dashboard of Instance-2(Port 8081) it is showing Instance-1 name. So far so good.

I have deployed them on external tomcat server as war and not running them as jar. War name is "eureka-naming-server". So my access URL becomes: http://localhost:8080/eureka-naming-server/eureka and http://localhost:8081/eureka-naming-server/eureka.

I have set up a load balancer using Apache 2 and mod_jk. So instead of accessing them using their individual URLs i.e. http://localhost:8080/eureka-naming-server/eureka, http://localhost:8081/eureka-naming-server/eureka, I can access them using Apache URL as http://localhost:80/eureka-naming-server/eureka and I can see load-balancing happening properly.

Now the issue is that once I give Eureka URL as http://localhost:80/eureka-naming-server/eureka in the microservice, it registers only on one instance depending on which Eureka instance the load-balancer has redirected the request. But even though peer to peer awareness is setup, microservice is not getting registered on the other eureka instance.

In Eureak servers, I'm using the below dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Eureka-1 props:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-naming-server
  jmx:
    default-domain: eureka-naming-server
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://eureka-server-2:8081/eureka-naming-server/eureka

    #register-with-eureka: false
    #fetch-registry: false
  instance:
    hostname: eureka-server-1
```

Eureka-2 props:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-naming-server
  jmx:
    default-domain: eureka-naming-server
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://eureka-server-1:8080/eureka-naming-server/eureka

    #register-with-eureka: false
    #fetch-registry: false
  instance:
    hostname: eureka-server-2
```

In microservices, I'm using below dependencies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Microservice props:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    metadata-map:
      configPath: /config
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost/eureka-naming-server/eureka
```

In the machine's /etc/hosts file I have set it up as:

```
127.0.0.1 eureka-server-1

127.0.0.1 eureka-server-2
```

The eureka instance on which it is getting registered I can see the below in the logs:

```
WARN 13748 --- [nio-8009-exec-3] Registered instance CONFIG-SERVER/192.168.1.16:config-server:8888 with status UP (replication=false)
```

The other Eureka instance where it is not registered, when it receives the heart-beat because of the load-balancer, shows this in the logs:

```
WARN 13748 --- [nio-8009-exec-3] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : DS: Registry: lease doesn't exist, registering resource: CONFIG-SERVER - 192.168.1.16:config-server:8888
2019-12-26 19:00:34.995  WARN 13748 --- [nio-8009-exec-3] c.n.eureka.resources.InstanceResource    : Not Found (Renew): CONFIG-SERVER - 192.168.1.16:config-server:8888
```

Eureka-1 Dashboard

[image]

Eureka-2 Dashboard

[image]

I have already tried suggestions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073447/unable-to-register-multiple-instance-of-eureka) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288959/eureka-peers-not-synchronized). But nothing seems to work.

So what could I be missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Issue:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-naming-server
```

You put the same name for an application so it's displayed like this.

you need to change it to,

Eureka-1 props:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-naming-server-1
```

Eureka-2 props:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-naming-server-2
```

Answer (score 1):

It may also be worth checking your security configuration for your eureka servers.  If you do have spring boot security enabled, you will need to be sure that you include the corresponding username/password in the defaultZone portion of your config.

i.e. in your eureka server 1 config: eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://:@eureka-server-2:8761/eureka

(and visa versa for your eureka server 2 config)

I only mention this because I had left out my own username/password values in that config value and it was not registering my microservices on all my eureka instances.  After make this change, it worked as I was expecting.